# Given a list of integers, return true if the length of the list is greater than 1

Tags: python

I'm try learning to Python and I need given a list of integers, return true if the length of the list is greater than 1 and the first element and the last element are equal. Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def solve(self, nums):
    nums = []
  if len(nums) > 1 and nums[0]== nums[-1]: 
      return True
```

return False

But I get this error:

```
if len(nums) > 1 and nums[0]== nums[-1]:IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: The `if` need to be inside the `def`. You also override `nums` parameter, it will always be an empty list.

Comment: The indent is wrong, plus you are replacing the variable ```nums``` (```nums = []```)

Comment: Also, your function won't return anything if the condition `len(nums) > 1 and nums[0]== nums[-1]` is false. At a minimum, you should add an `else: False`, or use @Jan's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write it like

```
class Solution:
    def solve(self, nums):
        return (len(nums) > 1 and nums[0] == nums[-1])
```

You were initializing the `nums` again and again to have zero elements plus the indention was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You got it almost right, `if` statement should be nested inside the `solve` method, however since you are returning `True` or `False` you can skip that and you don't need the nums `list` either, so do this:

```py
class Solution:
    def solve(self, nums):
        return len(nums) > 1 and nums[0]== nums[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 class Solution:
   def solve(self, nums):
     if len(nums) > 1 and nums[0]== nums[-1]: 
       return True
```

Comment: You shouldn't have the `nums = []` line.

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is an indentation error. In python, you should use either space or tab to represent body of a function or class ,like  curly braces in c++ or javascript. It is important to note that you should keep equal indentation for each line inside a body segment. i.e, if you start writing a function by giving 2 spaces as indentation,you should use 2 spaces for all the lines in the function body. The best way is to use tab instead of spaces so that you may not be confused with the number of spaces. Please take into account that you cannot use space and tab at a time.
I have edited your code as,

```
class Solution:
    def solve(self, nums):
          return (len(nums) > 1 and nums[0]== nums[-1])
```

you can call the function as,

```
obj=Solution()
obj.solve([1,2,3,4,1])
```